# Azure: Login page content appears too small in Windows 10 Phone

Tags: azure, windows-phone, uwp, windows-10-mobile

I am developing a UWP Application for Windows 10 phones using Azure. The problem is, that when the `LoginAsync` is called, the content of the login page appears too small at the phone screen  and the user needs to click on a textbox for the content to become bigger. Is there any way to fix this problem?

Comment: Can you include your code?  I'm assuming you should just increase the size of your textbox.

Comment: I am just calling LoginAsync("MicrosoftAccount") . And the user is redirected to https://myservice.azure-mobile.net/login/microsoftaccount. I don't have control over this page.